# How to play with more than 4 controllers in the same pc?

Tags: controllers, gang-beasts

I just recently got 4 wired xbox one controllers, and I want to use them with my other 2 controllers to play Gang Beast and Pummel Party, but it seems that the game only recognize the first 4 that give an input. I've been researching and it is supposed to allow 8 players at the same time (I can make that 4 players with controllers and 1 with Keyboard play at the same time).

Is there a software or something that can be used to play with the 8 controllers at the same time?

Comment: If the game only recognizes 4, then the problem lies with the game itself. I doubt an external utility would help much.

Answer (score 2):

This is a hard-coded limit in XInput API:

> The XInput API supports **up to four controllers** connected at any time. The XInput functions all require a *dwUserIndex* parameter that is passed in to identify the controller being set or queried. This ID will be in the range of 0-3 and is set automatically by XInput. The number corresponds to the port that the controller is plugged into, and is not modifiable.

[Getting Started With XInput in Windows applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xinput/getting-started-with-xinput#multiple-controllers)

Gang Beasts and Pummel Party both support up to 8 players. If you already have 4 Xbox One controllers then try connecting non-Xbox controllers.

For Pummel Party, you can also try enabling **Xbox Extended Feature Support** in Steam's controller settings and disabling **Use XInput** in Pummel Party's controller settings.

[Apparently steam has a way to allow for more than 4 xbox controllers?](https://www.reddit.com/r/localmultiplayergames/comments/qrtktm/apparently_steam_has_a_way_to_allow_for_more_than/)

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this for Gang Beasts.